# Get all thumbnails from onedrive

Tags: onedrive

I am trying to get all pictures from a folder which is called 'Pictures',
but i am getting bad request error, here is my code:

```
const uri = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/Drive/";

    $("#btLeshoto").click(function () {
        //set url for the leshoto folder
        url += uri + "Pictures/children?$top=1000&access_token=" + token;
        loadImages();
    })


function loadImages() {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        // beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);}

    }).then(function (data) {
}}
```

I have tried using apigee, but no succes. Maybe can someone help me with this ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want your URL to end up looking something like this:

`https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/Pictures:/children`

The main differences with what you currently have:

1. You need to specify a starting item, and so in this case we put `root` after `drive`.
2. To use a path you need to "switch" to the path semantics (so the URL segments won't be treated as parts of the object model), and similarly switched back to access the object model again. This is accomplished with the `:`